# Australia 417 WHV - Can I apply again for the same visa if I didn't enter in Australia before the "Must not arrive after" date?

Tags: visa, australia

I applied for my 3rd working holiday visa (417) back in March 2022, then I decided to leave later, so I stayed home. Anyway, my "Must not arrive after" date is March 2023.

Recently I had the opportunity to attend a course which I find very interesting for me and my future, so I'd like to join it, but it's going to finish in July 2023, way later than my Australian deadline.

I was wondering if there's any chance for me to complete this course without losing my WHV (of course, I could jump into Australia before the deadline and start the visa, then fly back home to complete my course, but I find it complete nonsense: too expensive and I'd waste 4 months of visa).

The solutions I figured out are 2 but, I'm afraid, neither of them is going to work:

1. ASK FOR AN EXTENSION OF THE DEADLINE. But it is already impossibile to speak with the Australian immigration; even if I could find a way, I'm afraid I'll just get ignored.
2. WASTE THIS VISA AND ACQUIRE IT AGAIN. In this case I'd only have wasted one application fee and it would be OK for me. Then, when I'm ready to go (before turning 35), I'll re-apply for the same visa, pay the fee again, and go.
   This would be great but, I fear, once the visa is granted for the first time it's gone; if it gets wasted, it can't be issued again: GONE.
   If someone can prove the opposite, it'd be amazing!

Do I have any other chance?

Comment: Third option would be to do the course another time, or perhaps remotely from Australia after work day, etc

Comment: Not possible, it's a practical course, can't be done remotely and it's a very particular course, happens very rarely, no way to attend it for next 2/3 years. Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: I’m in the same situation. Did you apply again and worked? I called the immigration and they told me the same thing, but I’m afraid that the visa gets rejects for already got the granted and won’t use….

Comment: No, I haven't applied again yet but I'm confident that it will works. If you check at the various conditions, there's nothing that goes against this condition (also check my answer underneath), plus I've the mail they sent in case of refusal! "Applying and not using" just makes the visa expired, it doesn't prevent from reissuing.

Comment: I'm also in the same situation and I've already asked the immigration,but I haven't got any clear answer too.
Is there anyone that was actually able to reapply for whv after it has expired without entering the country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some "investigations" and seems like the chances to get a deadline extension from the immigration (*option 1*) are very poor and I couldn't find any extra (*option 3*).

**But**, starting from these "simple" answers that I've found on the "Australia Forum" ([2018](https://www.australiaforum.com/threads/reapplying-for-an-unused-cancelled-whv-417.281647/) and [2019](https://www.australiaforum.com/threads/working-holiday-417-never-used-can-i-apply-again.290073/)), **seems that is possible to re-apply for the same visa if the applicant hasn't entered in Australia during his year** (*option 2*).

In fact, checking on the [visa webpage](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/third-working-holiday-417#Overview), there's nothing that looks preventing this situation.

This thing is more evident by making an application simulation: by starting the application for a new 417 visa, the applicant will find this question

[image]

the question explicitly ask if the applicant has been previously granted **AND** been in Australia as **the holder of a Third Working Holiday visa**.

By saying YES, the applicant **cannot go on**.

Otherwise, by saying NO (*my case, as I’ve been granted for the visa but never been in Australia with that visa*), the applicant **can go on** with the application, so should be alright.
(Of course, the applicant has to pay the application fee again. I don't believe is possible to require the first application fee refund.)

I've also sent an official enquiry to the Australian immigration. I'd be surprised if I'll ever get an answer but, in this case, I'll update my answer.

**UPDATE:** After 3 weeks, I got an answer from the Australian Immigration!
As it supposed to be confidential, I won't quote it but they basically said what I've already deducted:

> Currently no way to extend the visa.
>
> Possible to reapply for the visa after it has expired without entering the country (before reaching the
> age limit). It has to be paid again.

Answer (score 3):

Update: I finally got a good answer from the immigration. Fortunately it will work and it's said that
"Please note that in the event that you do not use your granted visa to enter Australia, you may re-apply again as long as you still meet the visa criterion."

Comment:  Good to hear that!